# MySQL SELECT using WHERE as date filter does not work

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am using the following `SELECT` script which successfully finds the values for `$payer_email`, `reminder_date` and `sub_expire_date`, but no data is being produced when I apply the commented out `WHERE` condition to the `SELECT`. The intention of the `WHERE` is to filter the values from the `SELECT` to only provide those values which point to the subscription expiry (`sub_expire_date`) thirty days ahead of time, but no values are derived when the values do exist.
Can anyone tell me why the `SELECT` fails upon the inclusion of the `WHERE`?

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
include_once("../real_conn/real_i_conn.php");
$reminder_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+30 days"));
echo $reminder_date . "<br><br>";
$sql = "SELECT sec_tblpurchased_secureareas.users_id, 
        sec_tblpurchased_secureareas.sub_expire_date, 
        DATE_ADD(sec_tblpurchased_secureareas.sub_expire_date, INTERVAL - 30 
        day) AS reminder_date, sec_tblusers.payer_email
        FROM sec_tblpurchased_secureareas
        INNER JOIN sec_tblusers ON sec_tblusers.recid = 
        sec_tblpurchased_secureareas.users_id";
//WHERE DATE_ADD(sec_tblpurchased_secureareas.sub_expire_date, INTERVAL- 30 day) = '". $reminder_date ."' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conni, $sql);
if ($result) {
    // Return the number of rows in result set
    $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $rowcount);
    echo "<br><br>";
}
while ($num = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    //echo $num;
    $payer_email = $num['payer_email'];
    echo $num['payer_email'] . "  <br>";
    $reminder_date = $num['reminder_date'];
    $reminder_date = date_create("$reminder_date");
    echo date_format($reminder_date, "Y/m/d") . " remind<br>";
    $sub_expire_date = $num['sub_expire_date'];
    $sub_expire_date = date_create("$sub_expire_date");
    echo date_format($sub_expire_date, "Y/m/d") . " expire<br><br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I don't get any error message. Just a blank screen. That's with the WHERE included. Without the WHERE, the echoes are all good. Note: I just edited the commented out part of the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very difficult to read, and the code you shared is invalid (the line before the commented out `//WHERE` line ends `";` but the line after starts `- 30` -- this absolutely won't compile.

That said, my best guess is that you're using `DATE_ADD` incorrectly.  Check out the documentation on it here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

Notice it returns a `DATETIME`, never a `DATE`.  If you wrap it in a [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) call, however, you might get what you want.

Comment: Exactly. `INTERVAL - 30 DAY` won't work. Either use `DATE_SUB()` if you want to subtract or use simple arithmetic.

Comment: @techouse I'm pretty sure -30 is still valid there

Comment: I stand corrected, it does work :O. I've just never seen this kind of syntax ever. Probably a bad practice as well.

Comment: I've used it in some PHP code where the offset time is dynamically generated.  Easier to just pass a negative number to the MySQL string than to have to call a different MySQL function for the value of the passed variable.

Comment: I updated my testing server to show x.sub_expire_date as today and the thing delivers the correct $payer_email, $reminder_date and $sub_expire_date. What I need though is a method of finding these three values thirty days ahead of x.sub_expire_date. I am aware of your correction but it is commented out. I left it the -30 code in place because I thought this would clarify what I have been trying. The code as it stands works correctly as far as it goes, but it does nothing when trying to find the information thirty days in advance. I need this data to trigger a thirty day reminder as a CRON.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I find this easier to read:

```
SELECT x.users_id
     , x.sub_expire_date
     , DATE_ADD(x.sub_expire_date, INTERVAL - 30 DAY) reminder_date
     , u.payer_email
  FROM sec_tblpurchased_secureareas x
  JOIN sec_tblusers u
    ON u.recid = x.users_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has been solved, indirectly. It looks like I just had to use

```
DATE_SUB(sec_tblpurchased_secureareas.sub_expire_date, INTERVAL 30 day) AS reminder_date
```

instead of DATE_ADD with a negative day value. This give me the variable I need to trigger the CRON.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: `DATE_ADD` supports negative intervals (as I already mentioned in the comments of my answer), so this wasn't the problem.